# How to pass variable arguments to base class

Tags: typescript

I want to use variable arguments in base class constructor. Same thing in derived class. The constructor can receive an unknown number of arguments, and I want to pass them to the base class constructor, for some processing. I didn't find any nice solution for that, and it seems this could be solved with [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which apparently is not present in TypeScript. It will be developed [in version 1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Roadmap) (am I right?):

```
class TSBase{
  constructor(...args: any[]){
    //do stuff with args
  }
}

class TSSomeController extends TSBase{
  constructor(...args: any[]){         
    //let base do some stuff
    //super(...args); //this doesn't work, but it would be cool... :)
  }
}
```

What is the best way of doing that in TypeScript? Can I use something like `super.prototype.apply`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've found out, the spread operator is not available yet.

**EDIT - Sidenote:** Actually, it works now in TypeScript 1.5. Just do `super(...args);`

As to the best way to do this pre TypeScript 1.5... it really depends, but here's one solution that doesn't involve changing any of the derived classes and keeps with what you're wanting to do:

```
class TSBase {
  constructor(...args: any[]) {
    if (this.constructor != TSBase && args.length === 1 && args[0] instanceof Array) {
      args = args[0];
    }

    // work with args here... for example:
    args.forEach((val) => console.log(val));
  }
}

class TSSomeController extends TSBase{
  constructor(...args: any[]){         
    super(args);
  }
}

new TSBase(3, 4);                 // 3, 4
new TSBase([3, 4]);               // Array[2]
new TSSomeController(3, 4);       // 3, 4
new TSSomeController([3, 4]);     // Array[2]
new TSSomeController([3, 4], 5);  // Array[2], 5
```

Basically, you can add a check in the base constructor to make the `args` array equal the first element only when being passed in from a derived class, when there is one argument, and when that argument is an array.

Answer (score 2):

In many cases having an `inherited` check helps. This is one of those:

```
class TSBase { 
  constructor( ...args: any[] ) {
    if ( this.constructor != TSBase ) args = args[0];

    //do stuff with args    
    console.log(args);
  }
}

class TSSomeController extends TSBase {  
  constructor( ...args: any[] ) {
    super(args);
  }
}


var base = new TSBase(1,2,3); // [1,2,3]
var child = new TSSomeController(1,2,3); // [1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an overloaded constructor to achieve this:

## With Overloads / Type Guards

```
class TSBase{
  constructor(args: any[]);
  constructor(...args: any[]);
  constructor(...args: any[]) {
    if (Array.isArray(args[0])) {
        args = args[0];
    }

    // Do stuff
  }
}

class TSSomeController extends TSBase{
  constructor(...args: any[]){         
    super(args);
  }
}
```

Although it looks like `constructor(...args: any[])` is repeated, it is worth remembering that you cannot directly call the implementation signature, so you have to list it as an overload option too.

This example would need to be adjusted if you intended to pass an array of arrays, as it would break the logic used in the test - but I presume you would want to really pass a typed array such as `string[]` or `MyType[]`, rather than `any[]`.

## Without Overloads / Type Guards

You can also achieve this without overloads and type guards:

```
class TSBase{
    protected args: any[];

    constructor(...args: any[]){
        this.args = args;
    }

    getArgs() {
        return this.args;
    }
}

class TSSomeController extends TSBase{
    constructor(...args: any[]){  
        super(null);
        this.args = args;    
    }
}

var a = new TSBase(1, 2, 3);
console.log(a.getArgs());

var b = new TSSomeController(4, 5, 6);
console.log(b.getArgs());
```

Comment: I don't get the super(null); I want to do something with args in TSBase.constructor

Comment: Go with the overload option if you want to use args in the constructor.