# Typescript cast to variable parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a function:

```
start(...args: any[]): void {
// some code
}
```

Whis function called from another `start` function like:

```
start(...args: any[]): void {
            if (args.length !== 3)
                throw "controller invalid args";
            this.url = args[2];
            args.slice(2, 1);
            super.start(args);
        }
```

so, internal call to `super.start` pushes invalid argumest. For example I have call:

```
start('user', 'pass', 'http://someUrl.com')
```

so i save third param to `this.url` and need to pass first and second params to `super.start`. TypeScript translate in way where an array (`args`) passed as first parametr, buy I need to pass this array as variable parameters. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: My recommendation for this can be found here, there are also alternate suggestions on that question (which is nearly identical to yours): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27709097/how-to-pass-variable-arguments-to-base-class/27711881#27711881

Comment: Example adapted to your question: http://bit.ly/13Wnz2u